# XAMPP php executing both if and else parts

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, session-variables

It is strange. My php code is executing both if and else parts. Following code starts where $_SESSION['abc'] is not set yet.

```
//echo $_SESSION['abc'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['abc'])){
  echo "not showing this echo";
  $_SESSION['abc'] = "new";
} else {
  echo " why it jumps here, in XAMPP?";
}
```

My actual code was more complex so I did it simpler as above. The above code is not echoing "not showing this echo"; even when $_SESSION['abc'] is not set. If I comment out the statement `$_SESSION['abc'] = "new";` it echoes "not showing this echo".

What I found out by now:

1. It is happening only in XAMPP, at production server same is working fine.
2. It happens when I make the else condition true in the if block. And that condition is setting a session variable.
3. I myself thought the code is executing twice or something but it is not.
4. And more importantly "if" condition is true, if you uncomment first line `echo $_SESSION['abc'];`, it will show undefined index error.
5. The weirdest feeling for me is, when it reaches `$_SESSION['abc'] = "new";` in "if" block, it jumps to "else", ignoring the echo line before it.

Weird!! Am I missing something or it is a XAMPP bug. Yes, the code is working as expected, on production server.

EDIT:
I would like to add that only for this behavior I also reinstalled XAMPP (for the latest version). 
And as to "how do I know if it sets session variable, while not echo the line before it", it prints `echo $_SESSION['abc'];` in else-block, but it shows undefined index error if I uncomment first line `echo $_SESSION['abc'];`

Code with echo line added in else-block.

```
//echo $_SESSION['abc'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['abc'])){
  echo "not showing this echo";
  $_SESSION['abc'] = "new";
} else {
  echo " why it jumps here, in XAMPP?";
  echo $_SESSION['abc'];
}
```

UPDATE 2018-06-03
I was doing the above code in Laravel. I tried the above code out of Laravel framework in a plain PHP file and it worked in XAMPP, as it should. So the new information is, this is not working in Laravel-XAMPP combination. Versions: Laravel 5.4 and XAMPP 7.2.5

NOW??

Comment: It's really unclear what the problem is. The title says "executing both if and else parts" but then you say "the above code is **not** echoing "not showing this echo"". So is it executing both branches or not? What is the actual output of that code?

Comment: First  it reaches up to `$_SESSION['abc'] = "new";` and sets the session variable, then jumps to else part. So, it is executing both part, although it  is not echoing the if-block echo.

Comment: ...how do you know that it sets the session if it doesn't print anything? It's pretty much impossible that it would somehow skip the echo line but execute the next line inside the same block.

Comment: @JJJ it does print session variable in else-block or afterwards but not before if-else. I added the new line in the code, above. And Yes I believe it is impossible so I am asking this for learning about it, otherwise my code is already working in production. What's wrong at  XAMPP?

Comment: @Asghar if you are doing this out of laravel you must provide your full code. It does not seem to be a strange behavior, it seems your provided code plays not well together with the framework. Please compare (Localhost, Remote) all your presets (PHP.ini, your framework vars, etc,. ) check also if you deployed the correct code to your server. Enable also error reporting in your framework or in PHP. If it is not working you must provide more details.

Comment: @Michael it behaves same with only above lines of code written in the blade file. And I already experimented the same blade and routing on server, that's working fine. I am fine with localhost and remote working because there are dozens of laravel projects which are working fine and same at localhost and server. Yes this was unbelievable when thinking in terms of PHP only, so I posted it. But now I think it is one of the other thing where Laravel and XAMPP (at localhost at least) do not get along well.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. You already suggested to go through PHP.ini in your other reply. Error reporting and logs are not helpful here because there is no error but only this 'strange' behaviour. 'if' and 'else' both, it is horror.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve. It looks like you are testing $_SESSION before you  assign a value to your session key.

Do a print_r ($_SESSION) to become clear when which value is assigned. And which value is stored after you reload your session. You can also printout your statement to see the result like `echo (!isset(value))` as an example.

```
session_start ();

print_r ($_SESSION);

if (!isset ($_SESSION ['whatever'])){

    echo "not set";
    print_r ($_SESSION);

} 
else {

      echo "set";
      print_r ($_SESSION);

}
```

Also try to change the first statement to be true if set and assign your new value in the else block

```
session_start ();

print_r ($_SESSION);

if (isset ($_SESSION ['whatever'])){

    echo "set";
    print_r ($_SESSION);

} 
else {

      echo "not set";
      print_r ($_SESSION);

      $_SESSION['whatever'] = "new value";

}
```

Hopefully it helps to find the faulty place

**Edit**

Be sure to use 
`session_start()` 
at very first line

or to set 
`session.auto_start = 1`
 in your php.ini

Comment: Thanks. `echo` before  `if-else` was already there. `echo` in else-block was also already tested and added in the question now. Please refer the edited part. And the code is actually working online, but not at XAMPP.

Comment: Check your PHP.ini settings an PHP Versions to get a clue what is different. Also when you provide the settings I can retest it on XAMPP

Comment: What I'm not sure about: Do you use session_start () on the very first line, when handling with $_SESSION?

Comment: Yes @Michael I do. And please check I made an update when you were writing this comment.

Comment: You are using the latest xampp version for windows. PHP 7.2 ?

Comment: Please set error_reporting(E_ALL); to reveal possible errors.